# Cypher find vector without edge of given type

Tags: agens-graph, opencypher

I'm trying to get vectors without a relationship with a certain label.

So using:

```
MATCH (a:"VectorName") WHERE NOT EXISTS ((a)-[]->()) return *;
```

will give me the VectorName nodes with out any outward relationships but can I do something like:

```
MATCH (a:"VectorName"), [b:"EdgeName"] WHERE NOT EXISTS ((a)-[b]->()) return a;
```

I'm using agensgraph not Neo4J so would like something that works for that.

Answer (score 0):

I found:

MATCH (a:"VectorName") WHERE exists((a)-[:"EdgeName"]->()) = 'f' return a;

Comment: What's wrong with it?